# Goals with same conversion rate

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a problem with my Google Analytics goals. 
I'm using Magento as CMS.

These are the funnels:

Goal 1:

Product page: something /product1
Cart: ^/checkout/cart/$
Customer details: ^/checkout/cart/step2/$
Destination: ^/checkout/onepage/success/

Goal 2:

Product page: something /product2
Cart: ^/checkout/cart/$
Customer details: ^/checkout/cart/step2/$
Destination: ^/checkout/onepage/success/

Both Goals have the same conversion rate.
But, I can see in the Ecommerce Product Performance section that products in Goal 1 convert in much higher numbers then products in Goal 2.
So the conversion rate should be different.

Why are the goals showing the same conversion rate?
The CMS is Magento.

Comment: Goal with the same destination url are the same goal, the funnel just affects visualization, not conversion. Plus since this is not about code it's probably off-topic for stackexchange and should rather go to webmasters.stackexchange.com (so if you have follow-up questions please ask there).

Comment: OK thanks. i may have found the solution here then:http://duntuk.com/magento-google-analytics-goals-setup